# How to add one event listener for two or more events in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where in I have two events like onClick & onSelect, I have same event handler for both. I want to know what is the best way to write in these cases, should we write a common method and then depending on event type call the event handler or there is some syntax that I can use in case event handlers are same. **Just wanted to save few bites of code if possible.** Also pls consider a situation where I have four event and same event handlers for all.

```
<HAComboLink 
  label= {toI18Text(intl, "edit")}
  value="edit" 
  onClick={onEditCustomFieldClick(id)} 
  onSelect={onEditCustomFieldClick(id)} 
  id="edit"
>
  <HAItem id="makeInactive" value="active" tabIndex="0">
    {toI18Text(intl, "make.inactive.label")}
  </HAItem>
</HAComboLink>
```

Comment: Not really feasible. Even if you had a global listener of some kind, that would only **add** more lines to your code, not save you any.

Comment: Yes that's right :)

Comment: The only think I can think of, if lines are really important to you would be to have a function calling your function. So something like `onClick={x(id)} onSelect={x(id)}` and then have `x()` call `onEditCustomFieldClick(id)`.... but eh... seems unnecessary?

Comment: This anyway will be done by build tools, isn't it? Just wanted to ask the community if there is some way we can do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I see often is to call the "common" handler in each of the separate event handler functions.

```
<Component onBlur={this.handleBlur} onInput={this.handleInput}  />

handleBlur = event => this.emitChange(event)

handleInput = event => this.emitChange(event)

emitChange = event => //do some common task
```